# what is the best laravel package to integrate more than one payment method?

Tags: laravel

I'm building an online courses website and I want to integrate more than one payment method.
Some people will pay through PayPal platform and some of them will pay through credit card or visa card. I'm also planning on integrating another platform called Payfort Platform.

What is the best package I can use to integrate more than one payment method and save me sometime and effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check omnipay, it has a consistent API to work with several gateways,and has a lot of gateways drivers available.

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay